# How can i transform my Boolean list of lists to 1s and 0s?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, python-imaging-library

```
   [[ True False False  True  True  True  True  True  True False False  True
   True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  False False  True  True  True  True False False False  True  True  True
  False False False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False False
   True  True  True False False  True]
 [ True False False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True False False  True  True  True False False  True  True False False
  False False False False  True  True False False False  True  True False
  False False False False  True  True  True False False False False False
  False False False False False False]]
```

assuming the outcome of `bw_np = numpy.asarray(bw)` is a list of lists althought i don't see commas, no commas between elements within sublists either?

What i tried:

```
for element in bw_np:
    for sub in element:
        sub = sub*1
        print(sub)
print(bw_np)
```

Comment: Why are you passing `bw` - which is already an image - to `Image.open`? Just pass it directly to `asarray`.

Comment: Works thanks for the comment, any quick way to turn the true falses i get to 1-0 and have my output in a window by itself the size of the image for better visualization.